# Php return float with currency format

Tags: php

Just trying to return a price in json from our API, this needs to be formatted as a float with two decimal place. Currently when I float it returns without the decimals but without float it returns as a string and I would like it as a float.

```
public function repairs(Collection $repairs) : Collection
{
    return $repairs->map(function ($repair) {
        return [
            "id" => $repair->id,
            "title" => $repair->problem->title,
            "price" => (float) $repair->price
        ];
    });
}
```

results in:

```
"repairs": {
    "411": {
        "id": 411,
        "title": "Screen",
        "price": 235.99
    },
    "419": {
        "id": 419,
        "title": "Charger Port",
        "price": 40
    },
    "582": {
        "id": 582,
        "title": "Back Glass",
        "price": 40
    }
}
```

Comment: _“Currently when I float it returns without the decimals but without float it returns as a string and I would like it as a float.”_ - that makes no sense to begin with, floats don’t contain any currency symbols. Anything that _does_ contain a currency symbol, is not a numeric value, but a string in any case. And whether you would even want to use float for monetary values to begin with, would be another question (and probably the more important one) - the inherent precision loss can easily cause problems, so usually you would work with integers in the currency’s lowest denomination anyway.

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs There's even [`money_format`](http://php.net/manual/function.money-format.php), yo

Comment: das ist true but @CBroe comment makes mine redundant - you can do something in html like this: `echo '&pound;'. (float)$var;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use round() or number_format(). Round returns a float, number_format returns a string. So you would probably prefer round():

```
    public function repairs(Collection $repairs) : Collection
    {
        return $repairs->map(function ($repair) {
            return [
                "id" => $repair->id,
                "title" => $repair->problem->title,
                "price" =>  round($repair->price,2)
            ];
        });
    }
```